# Random data returned from mysql database one after another?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database of facts and I want to display one of these facts at random for say 10 seconds then for it to choose another fact and display it for 10 seconds and so on.

Currently I can get it to display a random fact fine using the code below however I am a bit confused about how to show this for 10 seconds and then display a different fact. Any help or advice would be brilliant? Thanks.

```
<?php 
  $linkid = $_GET['linkID'];            
  $query  = "SELECT *  
               FROM facts 
           ORDER BY RAND() 
              LIMIT 1";

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $factxt = $row ['factxt'];
    echo $factxt;
  }
?>
```

Hi, ok I tried both of the ways suggested below, using ajax and jquery but both are returning the same error from the database:

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in getfact.php on line 4

This is line 4 of getfact.php,`$query  = "SELECT *  FROM facts order by rand() limit 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);`

is there something that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ajax with help of jQuery library.

Sample code:

```
setInterval(retrieveFact, 10000); // call retrieveFact() every 10 seconds

function retrieveFact() {
    // make an asynchronous call to getfact.php
    $.post('/getfact.php', function(data) { 
       // when it returns, set the content of div with id=#factbox
       $('#factbox').html(data); 
    });
});
```

Here, `getfact.php` would be the code you pasted on the question.

And in your html somewhere place the element that will receive the text:

```
<div id="factbox"></div>
```

More references:

- [How to setup jQuery in your
  pages](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery)
- [Documentation for
  post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [Documentation for
  jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Hi, ok I tried both of the ways suggested below, using ajax and jquery but both are returning the same error from the database:

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in getfact.php on line 4

This is line 4 of getfact.php,$query = "SELECT * FROM facts order by rand() limit 1"; $result = mysql_query($query);

is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: your mysql is not setup correctly. check if there are missing includes on the file.

Comment: Thankyou yes I was just being silly and bit tired and forgot to include the database.php include! Thank for your help its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

First you must to include the jQuery library, then use this example code.

somefile.php/html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getRand() {
$.ajax({
url: "getFact.php",
success: function(response) {
$("#random").html(response).hide().fadeIn("slow");
}
});
};
setInterval("getRand()", 10000);
</script>
<div id="random"></div>
```

getFact.php:

```
<?php 
$linkid = $_GET['linkID'];          
$query  = "SELECT *  FROM facts order by rand() limit 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$factxt= $row ['factxt'];
echo $factxt;
?>
```

When the LIMIT is 1, you don't need to put information into loop.

Comment: but you have to check if no results are returned

Comment: Hi, ok I tried both of the ways suggested below, using ajax and jquery but both are returning the same error from the database:

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in getfact.php on line 4

This is line 4 of getfact.php,$query = "SELECT * FROM facts order by rand() limit 1"; $result = mysql_query($query);

is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: In file getFact.php you will be connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this with an interval that loads in some data via ajax/getJSON or load this page in an iframe and add an automated refresh every 10 seconds (meta refresh).